# Did Android remove Fingerprint/Passcode for WebAuthN and lower security to push Passkeys?

Tags: android, tpm, webauthn, passkey

So, before this year, when you were using WebAuthN to create security keys on an up to date Android phone (Pixel 6 in my case), you had these options (iirc):

When creating a platform authenticator, you were offered Fingerprint/Passcode. When creating a roaming authenticator, you were asked to attach an USB or NFC Key. When you didn't specify the type to use, Android offered all 3 options.

Now this year with Passkeys introduced, this changed. When not specifying the type, or when specifiyng a platform authenticator, your only option is to generate a Passkey. Roaming is still USB and NFC.

Fingerprint/Passcode dosn't show up as an option anymore.

This concerns me, as my impression was that Fingerprint/Passcode actually used a hardware bound keypair, generated inside the TPM of my device. It could not be extracted in any ways.

Passkeys however are software generated keypairs and the private key gets synced with my google account.

Did Google here really remove the option to use the secure hardware in the device, or am I getting something wrong here?

You can test all of this on https://webauthn.io/ btw.